# How can I copy values to the left of an activecell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a script that enters a date in the active cell. I use the script only in column B. Now I want to copy a value from `D2` ( where `D2` is a number) to a cell left of the active cell. And then the value of `D2` + 1.

```
  function TimeStamp(){

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var Time=new Date();

  var timeStampFormat="dd.mm.yy";

  ss.getActiveCell().setValue(Time).setNumberFormat(timeStempelFormat);

}
```

Now my question is how can I copy the value of `D2` one cell left to my active cell (`timeStamp`) and then the value of `D2` + 1.

Comment: ```range.offset```

Comment: As a reference for the comment above, you can visit the [Class Range in Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

Comment: I tried range.offset and did not understand it. I'm pretty new to the whole thing. Can you explain that to me more exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
function timestampandoffset() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var Time = new Date();
    var timeStampFormat = "dd.mm.yy";
    ss.getActiveCell().setValue(Time).setNumberFormat(timeStampFormat);
    ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, -1).setValue((ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, 2).getValue()) + 1);
}
```

You can achieve your goal with just one extra line of code.

> ss.getActiveCell().offset(0,
>   -1).setValue((ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, 2).getValue()) + 1);

The key is making use of your starting location (in your case, it is the ActiveCell). **All the offset references are relative to this** - how many lines above or below, and/or how many columns to the left or the right.

There are three components to the code:
1) `ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, 2).getValue()`
This is the value from Column D. 
The offset (documented at [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset)) is "0,2": that is: same row as the ActiveCell, but 2 columns to the right(=Column D).

2) `(ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, 2).getValue()) + 1`
This takes the value in the offset cell/range (Column D) and adds one.

3) `ss.getActiveCell().offset(0, -1).setValue`
Lastly, this is the target cell. The offset is "0,-1": that is, the same row as the ActiveCell but one column to the left (=Column A).